# fire componentDidMount without having render method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use React and Redux in my app. I'm trying to make my container clear from any JSX code and even render method. I am trying to use my container just to fetch data and then at the export section I use `connect` and push those data to my other component that I have my JSX codes.

The problem is, when I did this I noted that the redux-action I have in the `componentdidMount` to fetch the data wasn't run and I noted that is because my `componentDidMount` didn't get called.
So what shall I do?

Comment: What is your use case for not having a `render` method? As I see it, React lifecycle methods such as `componentDidMount` shouldn't be used if you have no `render` method

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is that `componentDidMount` is only called after `render` succeeds. This means that you shouldn't even expect it to get called if you have no render. Part of the idea with React lifecycle methods is that they revolve around rendering and state but if you have no render, changes to state and detecting re-renders as `componentDidMount` is meant to do can't happen. `componentDidMount` implies that there is something to mount which is the job of the `render` function.

If you look at [this diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) you can see there is no work around to call a lifecycle function dependent on `render` without it. `render` is the only thing that can trigger changes to the `DOM` to which `componentDidMount` listens.

Perhaps consider doing something like explained in the `componentDidMount` section [here](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8747/react-lifecycle-methods-render-and-componentdidmount) where your render returns the data that `componentDidMount` collects and then that state could be used in your other components as props.

Read more about React lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)